# Why can't I get the content stream from multiple OpenCMS documents using VB.Net/dotCMIS.dll?

Tags: vb.net, opencmis

I'm using the OpenCMIS [dotCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html) library to read documents from CMIS-compliant repositories.

I have parallel Java/Chemistry and VB.Net/dotCMIS test programs talking to the same FileNet fncmis repository.

I can connect, query, fetch the documents OK, in either Java or VB.Net.

PROBLEM: In VB.Net, I can only read content from the *first* document.  The second and subsequent documents give me a content stream ... but I get exactly zero bytes.  Java works fine.  VB.Net fails after the first document.

There are no compile warnings or runtime exceptions.

QUESTION: Can you see any reason subsequent calls to `DisplayDocument()` would have zero bytes?

I'm using the latest version of dotCMIS, Release 0.7.

```
Option Explicit On

Imports DotCMIS.Client
Imports DotCMIS.SessionParameter
    ...
    Public Sub DisplayDocument(ByVal document As IDocument)
        ...
        ' Open stream to document content and copy to a file
        Dim contentStream As DotCMIS.Data.IContentStream = document.GetContentStream()
        sFilePath = "c:\temp\" & contentStream.FileName
        Using fis = contentStream.Stream
            Using fos = New System.IO.FileStream(sFilePath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Dim buffer(2048) As Byte
                Do While (i = fis.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                    fos.Write(buffer, 0, i)
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved!

In retrospect, it had nothing to do with OpenCMIS and everything to do with .Net streams: I simply forgot to specify `IO.FileAccess.Write` when I opened the .Net output stream.

Here is the corrected code:

```
    ' Open stream to document content and copy to a file
    Dim contentStream As IContentStream = document.GetContentStream()
    sFilePath = "c:\temp\" & contentStream.FileName
    Using fis = contentStream.Stream
        Using fos = New System.IO.FileStream(sFilePath, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            Dim buffer(2048) As Byte
            Do
                i = fis.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                If i > 0 Then fos.Write(buffer, 0, i)
            Loop While i > 0
        End Using
    End Using
```